# Get text from <td> tag using Selenium

Tags: c#, html, selenium

I am working through the following table.  I want to grab the value within the `<td>` tag that contains 30.0000, but whenever I try to grab it with Selenium, it returns 0.0000.  I have tried `findElementByXPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00__0']/td[6]).Text` where the text reads as:

> `<td align="center">30.0000</td>`

No other selenium command seems to even find it.  Does anyone know why I can not get the value out of this table? Thank you.

```
<tr id="ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00__0" class="rgRow">
    <td class="rgExpandCol">
        <img style="border-width:0px;" alt="Collapse" src="/Images/icons/collapse-icon.png" onclick="$find("ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00")._toggleExpand(this, event); return false;" title="Collapse"/>
    </td>
    <td>ROS50462</td>
    <td>ENSURE CHOCOLATE ENTERAL FOOD UNIT/CAN</td>
    <td>Can(s)</td>
    <td style="width:50px;">
        <span id="ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00_ctl04_txtQuantity_wrapper" class="riSingle    RadInput RadInput_Office2007" style="width: 40px;">
    </td>
    <td align="center">30.0000</td>
    //rest of table....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try different approach. Locate the previous sibling and go from there

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//[@id='ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00_ctl04_txtQuantity_wrapper']/../following-sibling::td")).Text;
```

Comment: What benefit is there to look at the prior sibling?  Does this make the code look at it "from a different angle," for lack of better words?

Comment: @Rinktacular The `xpath` you used is relaying on the location of the `<td>` tag you want to be the six `<td>`. If some tags where added/removed via JavaScript it will change the tag's relative position so `td[6]` won't be relevant anymore.

Comment: It might not happen though and than there won't be any difference.

Comment: interesting, Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The text in your element is most probably equal to "0.0000" at the time you try to read it.
I would try to exclude the default value and wait for it:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0,0,5));
WebElement element = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(
  By.XPath(".//*[@id='ctl00_c_dgPOItems_ctl00__0']/td[6][text()!='0.0000']")));
```

Comment: Ah I did not thank of that, I'll try to set a wait then